# How to trace the variable?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

When the update button clicked, the alist would be update, how can I get the update value and can choose in the combobox? Thanks very much!

```
namespace eval PreGen {
    set alist {sec1 sec2 sec3 sec4}
    proc SetUp {} {
        ttk::combobox .c -values $PreGen::alist
        button .b -text update -command PreGen::Update
        grid ...
    }
    proc Update {} {
        ...
        set PreGen::alist {op1 op2 op3 ...} #the list value got from other file
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trace easily enough. It's clearest with a helper procedure to implement the trace callback, but you could use an `apply` term instead; that would work as well, but the code is a bit more opaque because it crams more on one line. Here's the procedure version:

```
namespace eval PreGen {
    # ALWAYS use [variable] to set default values for variables
    variable alist {sec1 sec2 sec3 sec4}

    proc SetUp {} {
        variable alist
        ttk::combobox .c -values $alist
        trace add variable alist write ::PreGen::AlistUpdated
        # Could use [namespace code] to generate the callback:
        #   trace add variable alist write [namespace code AlistUpdated]
        # but that feels like overkill in this case
        button .b -text update -command PreGen::Update
        grid ...
    }

    proc AlistUpdated {args} {
        # We just ignore the arguments; don't need them here
        variable alist
        .c configure -values $alist
    }

    proc Update ...
}
```

Of course, if you only ever set the variable from within procedures in that namespace, you could just call `.c configure -values` at the right time directly. That's what I'd actually recommend you do.